# Shell Scripting passing arguments to a system binary and storing the value

Tags: shell, scripting, cron, asterisk, elastix

I've been trying to get this to work on a few occasion but I seem to be having a bit of trouble.

`asterisk -rx "core show calls" | grep "active" | cut -d' ' -f1`

The asterisk command runs from `/usr/sbin/asterisk` Launching it like so, executes the asterisk executable and pipes the output, grep for active calls.
I usually get an Integer value which I would like to store in a variable and keep working the script from there.

I'm having a rough time passing arguments to the command.

I'm basically trying to make that command into a SHELL SCRIPT and store the value.

Can you guys, point me towards the right direction ?

Comment: Arguments to what command? What arguments are you trying to pass? What have you tried? What isn't working exactly?

Comment: I tried something like this : `#!/bin/sh

echo -e "/usr/sbin/asterisk $1";`

Comment: You tried that where? Called how? What about that didn't work? Where are you expecting the script when run by cron to get arguments from (assuming that's the question here)?

Comment: To be honnest I haven't even setup the cron job yet, I just want to be able to write a script that can pass arguments to asterisk. Doing that command above outputs a value, I want to use that value as variable and work from there.

Comment: I'm entirely unclear at this point what your actual question is. Is it "how do I store the output of a command in a variable"? Is it "how do I pass arguments to a cron job"? Something else?

Comment: Fine, I'll modify the title and try to be a little more concise, using this command above (which uses the asterisk binary file I believe written in C ) I should pass argument to it like you see above : `-rx "core show calls" |  grep "active" | cut -d' ' -f1` that command should execute and I'm trung to store a the value, so I can work on it.

Comment: Only `-rx "core show calls"` are arguments to `asterisk` and you know how to pass them to it (your example command in the post is correct). That whole pipeline is valid (assuming that `active` is the keyword you need and that `cut` finds the correct field on each line. If the question is then how do you store that in a variable and use it in your calculation of count later that's a *wildly* different question then this started with.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
active=$(asterisk -rx "core show calls" | awk '$2=="active"{n=$1} END{printf("%d",n)}')
```

This uses awk's `printf` to make sure that if the active calls line is skipped in your output, your variable is assigned a `0` instead of being blank.

Or alternately, if your shell is bash, you could use this to avoid all the pipes:

```
while read active what _; do
  if [ "$what" = "active" ]; then
    break
  fi
done < <(asterisk -rx "core show calls")
```

At the end of this loop, if no "active calls" lines were seen, `$active` will be blank, so if you want, you could add:

```
active=${active:-0}
```

to assign a zero value if no active calls are reported.

(In my tests, `0 active calls` does get reported with each run, so all this blank handling is just insurance.)

Comment: I like this, but the value if no calls is ALWAYS 0. i'm thinking of setting up a cron job that will alert me if calls go over 10 for example. However I'm looking for something much more simple since this is one of my first bash scripts.

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is a monitoring system.  I use [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) which has [plugins for Asterisk](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Telephony/Asterisk) but you might find [Zabbix](http://zabbix.com/) easier to manage.  You might also find [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) or some other [RRDtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/)-backed system useful.  Have a look at the [Asterisk monitoring page at voip-info.org](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+monitoring).

Comment: Thanks @ghoti I will into it, I haven't had luck configuring Nagios properly, the other one I never heard about. I did play around with bash scripting this morning and found a solution. I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [example](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_02.html) 7.2.2.2 , i had modified it to work around what I was trying to accomplish,
So if I have more than let's say 5 calls running everytime the program runs, then alert me by email.

```
#!/bin/sh

rast=`asterisk -rx 'core show calls' | grep 'active' | cut -d' ' -f1`
maxvalue="5"

echo "Program started"

if [ "$rast" -ge "$maxvalue" ]; then
  echo "More than one calls processed" | mail -s 'Verify Calls from '`uname -n` hayonj@example.com
else
  echo "No active calls" | mail -s 'Crontab executed from '`uname -n` hayonj@example.com
fi

echo "Program Terminated"
```

saved the file under `verify.sh` I placed it where the binary for asterisk is located in `/sbin/` and used `chmod a+x verify.sh` to set execute permissions to the script.

Afterwards, i simply set it up like so with a crontab, 
`crontab -e` and `* * * * * /sbin/verify.sh`

This little example, was my first bash script to automate my daily tasks.

Answer (score 0):

All other examples will not work if your asterisk have single peer with name "active"

Note, for this task simple do

```
asterisk -rx 'core show calls' |tail -n 2 | head -n 1|cut -f 1 -d\
```